# Cannot create linked tables in Access for Office 365

Tags: ms-access, office365, linked-tables

I have an Access database on Office 365 and I need to create linked tables to Azure SQL database. "Linked Table Manager" is greyed out, so I tried going to External data -> ODBC database  and selecting option "Link to data source by creating a linked table". Then I proceed to create an ODBC connection which does not seem to show up in Access even though it gets created on my machine. Can anyone help me diagnose an issue or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Once you have created a working DSN, use it to create the linked table.

Comment: That's the thing - I have a working ODBC connection but cannot access it from Access. No pun intended

Comment: What kind of DSN is it (user, system...) ?

Comment: As a workaround, you can also create a passthru query, set the proper ODBC Connect Str and write your SELECT. This way, no DSN used.

Comment: I have it in the list of ODBC connections on my machine but cannot find the actual file path

Comment: try creating a user dsn instead.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Btw, how come it wanted User DSN instead of System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a user DSN instead. I prefer them anyway, since you don't need that DSN on client machines when you deploy.

Comment: Do you know why would it see user dsn but not system?

Comment: Don't know. But on most clients sites I work (banks) you can't create a machine data source because you don't get the privileges (they are written into the registry).